# Sort "usings" directive by ReSharper Clean-up

Tags: resharper, using-statement, code-cleanup

How to setup ReSharper to call "Sort usings" in class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will answer for my question.

Using shortcut from Resharper it's not best solution. Nice tool is [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) it makes few nice cleanup's when saving file like with no shortcut key press:

- sorting usings alphabetically and remove unused
- deleting empty lines

This tool is complement for Resharper.

Answer (score 8):

Try using the [Stylecop Resharper Plugin](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)

`Stylecop Rule SA1210: Using directives must be sorted alphabetically by the namespaces` will allow you to use a quick fix to sort them by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Using Stylecop is good at helping you write clean code, but you may want to turn off some of the rules.

Comment: +1 It is easy to use StyleCop to waste your time if you have too many rules turned on.

Answer (score 8):

Resharper (9) will sort usings if you run Code Cleanup, via menus or keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You don't need ReSharper to do this. By Default the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> will remove (unused) and sort the using statements.

If you only want sorting or the shortcut isn't set on your instance of Visual Studio, go to:

- Tools-> Options.
- Environment -> Keyboard
- Search for "Editor.ContextMenus.CodeWindow.OrganizeUsings".

There are a few options there to play with.

Comment: This doesn't really work - resharper overrides the newly bound shortcut every time after I press "OK".

Comment: This is probably dependent on the version of VS and ReSharper. Couldn't get this keystroke to work. However, clicking on the USING statement with resharper pops up a lightbulb icon, which includes the option to remove and sort.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 the name changed to: "EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.RemoveAndSort"

Comment: As of 2019: "Edit.SortUsings"

Comment: @DannyThunder - The name is still "EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.RemoveAndSort" even in Visual Studio 2022. The one you mentioned "Edit.SortUsings" only sorts, and is not removing unused ones.

Answer (score -5):

This question already covers this:

[Remove unused Usings across entire assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335940/remove-unused-usings-across-entire-assembly)

> The feature is in ReSharper 4.5. If you right click on the solution,
>   there's a Cleanup Code... item, which allows you to apply a cleanup
>   profile to the solution. You can create a new cleanup profile from the
>   Code Cleanup node within ReSharper options, if you want a profile to
>   just adjust the using directives.

Comment: on my VS this only removes not used directives, that's why I'am asking

Comment: Do you mean alphabetically "sort" then? Your question is very vague..!
I thought you mean sort as in "sort out"! Sorry if I misinterpreted.

Comment: Yes, I want to sort alphabetically by resharper not VS.