# Remove Unused Namespaces from entire project/solution

Tags: visual-studio

Is there an easy way to remove unused ***using*** namespaces from the entire project or solution?

I know that you can remove the unused namespace of a particular class by

> right click on using namespace statements >> Ogranize Usings >> Remove Unused Usings

But doing this for each and every class of the solution would be very tiresome.

I guess Resharper also allows doing this, but we are not using this tool.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56395251/1069816

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Visual Studio does not offer this functionality. However there are extensions (other than Resharper) that do it, take a look for example at [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) (it's free).

Comment: This is a good extension to recommend. To remove unused namespaces, just right on project/solution >> Power Commands >> Remove and Sort using. It also provide many useful features also which I've yet to explore.

Comment: This tool not supporting latest version of visual studio.  can suggest any alternative?