# Replacement for Edit.RemoveUnusedUsings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2015 had a menu item called "Edit.RemoveUnusedUsings", which I used frequently (I assigned it to `Ctrl+U` for convenience).

Visual Studio 2017 does not appear to have this feature.

Is there any way to access this function in Visual Studio 2017, preferably in a guise that allows me to assign it to `Ctrl+U`?

(Note: There is still an "Edit.RemoveAndSort" item, but it does nothing when I assign it to `Ctrl+U` in the Text Editor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a comment that should address this on [How to remove unused using namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075909/how-to-remove-unused-using-namespaces)

> in VS 2017 this is broken out into the Power Commands extension

Comment: Thanks - more info here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/03/06/productivity-power-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/